# Serial string sent to raspberrypi app gives unexpected result

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi

If I send the following string to the rpi via serial comms

```
echo "#q10"  > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Edit:
This is the app output from the raspberry pi (The linefeed character ^M seems to be the problem)

[image]

I have tried different length strings that also give inconsistencies

The code is as follows. I am using the serial wiring library from 
[Gordons project](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/serial-library/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd;

struct obj_Properties
 {
   char *one;
   char *two;
   char *three;
   char *four;
};

int main()
{
if ((fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)) < 0)
{
return 1;
}

for(;;){
while (serialDataAvail (fd))
 {
 struct obj_Properties prop;
 prop.one = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.two = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.three = serialGetchar(fd);
 prop.four = serialGetchar(fd);
 printf ("%c %c %c %c\n", prop.one, prop.two, prop.three, prop.four);

 fflush (stdout) ;

}
usleep(10000);
}
}
```

Comment: I've had similar problems before, turned out the serial was sending the \r character (carriage return) with each message which caused all sorts of problems showing the message in the terminal

Comment: Hmm, you cannot possibly get `#1q10` from that printf() statement.  Post your real code.

Comment: http://pastebin.ca/2834708 Why would I post the wrong code?@HansPassant I just ran it again and it is doing the same

Comment: @OscarRobinson did you manage to strip out the cr?

Comment: Yes you just iterate over the string and put it in a new array.  If a character=='/r' then don't copy it in.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried "%ls", "%s" but kept getting runtime errors, please if you have better suggestions I am always keen to learn

Comment: Agree with @HansPassant.  How does `printf ("%c %c %c %c\n", ...`, which should print something line "A B C D\n" ever print "#1q10"?  I would expect `echo "#q10"  > /dev/ttyUSB0` to cause "# q 1 0\n" to print.  Either the code posted does not match the real code or the output reported does not match the real output.

Comment: OK @chux it prints "# q 1 0\n", how does that add to the question of why it changes? I did notice that after about 10 seconds it reset so it may be an issue with the libarary

Comment: 1) Suggest editing the corrected output "# q 1 0\n" into the post.  2) Is the "#q \n 0 " an accurate example of unexpected output?  3) Suggest debugging with `static int n=0; printf ("n:%d %d %d %d %d\n", n++, ...` to better see unprintable data.

Comment: Thanks I can do something with that